# how to show popup with user control when clicking a button in webform?

Tags: asp.net, popup

i want to create a **popup window** when clicking on a button in **webform** and after that i want to show a  user control in that popup.how to do in asp.net?
          i tried with some jquery methods but nothing happens when clicking button?
i want to create a **popup window** when clicking on a button in **webform** and after that i want to show a  user control in that popup.how to do in asp.net?
          i tried with some jquery methods but nothing happens when clicking button?

Answer (score 0):

Think about using an IFrame to achieve this, from the sounds of what you are talking an IFrame would suffice and provided the needed functionality.

```
<iframe src="YOUR PAGE HERE"></iframe>
```

There's a lot more you can do with it, these are just the tags to get you going.